# getting cakephp to recognise my multiselect dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I have a form in a cakephp app which uses the sumoselect plugin to allow me to have multiselect dropdowns. However when the form gets posted, the $this->request object(?) doesn't have the values selected in it.

Curiously, if I remove all other form fields which were produced with the Form helper, then the data is there.

```
<label>Locations</label>
<select multiple="multiple" name="data[SplashPage][locations]" id="SplashPageLocations"> 
    <option value="1">KFC</option>
    <option value="2">General Merchants</option>
</select>
```

is the actual form input. There is no actual 'locations' field in the Splash_page table, the locations are something which I need to save elsewhere. But surely that doesn't make a difference?

Also, I've tried moving that input up so that it's the first thing in the form. And that appears to work. Problem is, that's not where the input should appear. If anyone can enlighten me why this is happening, you'll be very appreciated. And hopefully win the lottery or something.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the select input to

```
name="data[SplashPage][locations][]"
```

This way, you can send multiple values (selected)